# What makes the spinner disappear?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

In Magento 2 admin grid system, the one that uses ui-components, while the content of the grid is loading there is a spinner over the grid content.
[image: spinner].

When the grid is loaded, the spinner goes away.  [image: no-spinner]

What's the code js that makes it disappear when the grid contents are loaded?

Comment: `magento\vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\ui_component\templates\listing\default.xhtml` & Example `magento\vendor\magento\module-cms\view\adminhtml\ui_component\cms_block_listing.xml` file's `<item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">cms_block_columns</item>`

Comment: Your comment makes me realize I may have worded my question wrongly. I know how to add a spinner to the grid. I'm curious on the JS code that makes it go away when the grid finishes loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**magento\vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\grid\listing.js**

```
/**
 * Handler of the data providers' 'reloaded' event.
 */
onDataReloaded: function () {
    resolver(this.hideLoader, this);
}
```